# UART communication on STM32F4 data is not being received as expected - C

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, uart, stm32f4

I'm working on an embedded systems project using the STM32F4 Discovery board and trying to **establish UART communication between the board and an external module**. I've written the following code, but I'm facing issues with receiving data.

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"

void USART2_Init() {
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_USART2EN;
    
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE2_1;  // PA2 as alternate function
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE3_1;  // PA3 as alternate function
    
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (7 << (4 * 2));     // AF7 for USART2_TX (PA2)
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (7 << (4 * 3));     // AF7 for USART2_RX (PA3)
    
    USART2->BRR = 0x0683;  // 9600 baud @ 16MHz
    USART2->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_RE | USART_CR1_UE;
}

void USART2_SendChar(char ch) {
    while (!(USART2->SR & USART_SR_TXE));
    USART2->DR = ch;
}

char USART2_ReceiveChar() {
    while (!(USART2->SR & USART_SR_RXNE));
    return USART2->DR;
}

int main() {
    USART2_Init();
    
    while (1) {
        char receivedData = USART2_ReceiveChar();
        USART2_SendChar(receivedData); // Echo received data back
    }
}
```

I've double-checked my connections and ensured that the baud rates match between the STM32F4 and the external module. However, when I send data from the external module to the STM32F4, the received data is not being echoed back as expected.

Can anyone help me figure out what's happening?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the PA2 and PA3 are not connected to on-board ST-Link on a DISCOVERY STM32F4. Have you connected them with a separate USB-to-serial solution, or soldered flying leads?

Comment: They're soldered.

Comment: Are no data at all echoed, or are some echoed but changed? You might want to [edit] your question and add examples of sent data and what you received.

Comment: In addition to TX and RX, you also need a signal ground. What makes you think this is a software issue to begin with? Check the signals with your oscilloscope.

Comment: Clear UART flags before receiving and sending. Sometimes if some of those flags are set, the peripheral will refuse to work (applies to other peripherals too). Clear all transfer complete falgs and all of that sort, see if anything changes. If your code in receive functions forever sits in that while, I would also pause it at some point at look at UART flags, maybe something will look off. If possible, scope the line. Get an Arduino send stuff (remember about voltage levels, your MCU's pin can be 5V tolerant too) with an example sketch to rule out possible module issues.

Comment: I've tested your code with an STM32F401CC, which should be close enough. It works without changes. So the problem is most likely not in software.

Comment: @Codo thanks, man, for giving so much attention to it. You're right. I sent my code to a friend of mine who has the same hardware, and it worked. I'll now find out what happened to my board. Anyways, thanks once again.